# Does equations of motion work for distance and speed?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, speed, distance, displacement

In some books,when solving to find the distance and speed of the object having motion in straight line,the three equation of motion are used.so my question is whether these equation of motion (i.e $v=u+at$, $s=ut+(1/2)at^2$, $v^2-u^2=2as$) can be used to find speed and distance in general or it can only be used to find speed and distance if the speed and distance of the object is equal to velocity and displacement of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations you listed are "canned" in the sense they make assumptions from the more general laws (such as constant acceleration and constant velocity), then calculated out, and simplified. The more general forms require calculus and it was through calculus that the equations you listed were derived.

For example, the more general form is this:

$d=\int^b_a v(t)dt=\int^b_a\int^b_a a(t)dtdt$

$v(t)=\int^b_a a(t)dt$

What does this mean? That is an integral. The opposite of a derivative. A derivative calculates the slope of any point in function while the derivative calculates the area under the curve between two points on the x-axis, or time-axis in this case.

When you do $\int^b_a f(t) dt$ it means you took the function y=f(t) and calculated the area underneath the curve between the where t was greater than a and less than b. In other words, you accumulated all the small changes in velocity that result in the varying acceleration to give you the velocity at any point in time. Similarly, you can do that again to the velocity and that gives you the distance at any point in time. And since you perform this operation on a function v(t) or a(t) and functions can vary in time, it means the acceleration and velocities need not be constant.

The simple examples I gave are for one-axis of motion only. There are vector forms for two or three dimensions and in this case displacement velocity, and acceleration are vectors. For example:

$\bar d=[d_x(t), d_y(t), d_z(t)]$

$\bar v=[v_x(t), v_y(t), v_z(t)]$

$\bar a=[a_x(t), a_y(t), a_z(t)]$

Although nothing is stopping you from splitting these all up and calculating things one axis at a time.

---

In usage, we can be a bit sloppy with the terms "distance" and "displacement" because we usually know what we really mean regardless of what we say due to context. I sloppily almost always say distance when I really mean displacement:

- **Displacement** is position relative to an origin, regardless of the path taken to get there (i.e. a direct line, a vector if you will,
  from the origin to the destination. It has a direction and magnitude relative to the origin and is thus a vector.
- **Distance** is the cumulative path taken to get there. It has no direction and is always positive.

You can see from how the equations work (accumulating both positive and negative values of $\bar v(t)$ together), that $\bar d(t)$ is the displacement, not distance.

Imagine I walk in a full circle. Displacement is zero because I returned to where I started but obviously the distance I travelled is not zero. With this example in mind, if you look math definition it should be obvious that it is giving displacement. It may be easier to think of just one axis of motion where I walk in a straight line and then turn around back to where I started. In that case the the total area under the $v(t)$ curve would be zero because it has just has much positive area as negative area, thus resulting in zero displacement, but obviously the distance traveled was not zero.

To get distance you need to apply do arc length calculations on $\bar d(t)$to and accumulate the absolute value of all the incremental changes in d(t) over time. Don't actually take that approach literally though because it is real messy because you need to look at the path geometry and it's bad enough in one dimension, let alone two or three dimensions.

In practice you would instead find the magnitude of the $\bar v(t)$ to get speed and then integrate speed to get distance. $\bar a(t)$ would still be integrated normally to get $\bar v(t)$

$\text{distance}=\int^b_a\sqrt{ v_x(t)^2+v_y(t)^2+v_z(t)^2}dt=\int^b_a |\bar v(t)|dt=\int^b_a |\int^b_a \bar{a(t)}dt|dt$

where $|\bar v(t)| = \sqrt{ v_x(t)^2+v_y(t)^2+v_z(t)^2}$

I believe you end up with this method anyways if you go about the arc length thing just the right way since "incremental changes in d(t) over time" sounds a lot like velocity doesn't it? Which would make the absolute value value of that mentioned earlier the speed. And "accumulat[ing] [that] over time" is just integration.

Answer (score 1):

Those equations are valid for a point particle or rigid body undergoing constant acceleration in a straight line. They can also be used to describe one direction of motion in 2 dimensions, especially where acceleration is only in 1 direction, e.g. a ballistic projectile under the influence of gravity.

Comment: does those equation work for scalar quantity(distance or speed)?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  All of the quanties in those equations are scalars.

Comment: suppose a ball is vertically launched from the ground,it reaches hieght h and then falls back to ground.so when the ball reaches the ground the distance is 2h but displacement is zero.

Comment: distance is scalar and displacement is vector.

Comment: so i am asking if the equation will work for scalar i.e(distance).

Comment: That is not the correct definition of scalar and vector. The displacement you describe is the subtraction of two scalar positions, and thus is itself a scalar.  Both position and displacement can also be vectors, if they have a magnitude and direction. But $s$ in your equations is position, aka total displacement (from zero).  It is all scalars in those equations

Comment: but in the internet it is written  that displacement is strictly vector and distance is scalar.velocity is displacement/time and it has direction so I think since the equation of motion have velocity ,displacement is vector

Comment: Unfortunately the internet is not the place to learn physics.  Unless it's a real university lecture like the online MIT lectures.

Comment: @hsdfasdafhakdfhasiog See my answer for your question about distance vs displacement.